# Laravel pass data to vue component

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm passing through data from laravel into my vue component in order to be able to use VueJS however in my for each statement, the loop ends after the first set of data and does not show everything.

```html
 <div>
            <v-card-title>{{course}}</v-card-title>
            <v-card-subtitle>{{school}}</v-card-subtitle>
</div>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
    name:"InputForm",
    props: ['course', 'courseGroup', 'school'],
}
</script>
```

This is the blade code that im using to pass data to vue

```html
@foreach ($modules as $module)
<input-form  
            :course="'{{$module->Course}}'" 
            :school="'{{$module->School}}'"
/>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

use `json_encode()` function to send data to vuejs

```php
@foreach ($modules as $module)
<input-form  
            :course="{!! $module->Course !!}" 
            :school="{!! $module->School !!}"
/>
@endforeach
```

Comment: The data was being sent using the other method, its just it didnt show all of the data just the first set

Comment: did't get u can u explain in detail

Comment: So in the database, I have two entries for both course and school. The foreach is meant to go through each entry and pass it through to vue. However in this case it only passes the first entry since vue only shows the name of the first couse and school.

Comment: I mean it works if i do it manually in the blade file, but it only breaks when i pass it through to the vue component

Comment: loop is breaking or data inside component .?

Comment: the loop is breaking

Comment: There is no error message, the loop just doesnt show every entry

Comment: When i use json_encode i get " ""=""> ""=""> " instead of the actual data, whereas when i use the method i used, I only recieve the first data entry

Comment: now try this it should work as that us java script exp.

Comment: Remove the colons. Use,  course="{{@json($module->Course)}}”  if course is an array, or course="{{$module->Course}}” if course is a string